# Cannot forward when going through Welcome screen in fedora 15

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I just installed Fedora 15 on my laptop, but I have problem to make it working.

My current situation is that when the installation is done, it reboots and gives me the Welcome screen.

I setup username as usual, but when it comes to the "Date and Time" screen, it won't let me proceed any further: I press "Forward" button but nothing happens.

Does anybody has the same issue, and how did you solve that?

Comment: How long did you wait (after pressing "forward")?  If you told it to "synchronize date & time over the network", it may sit and wait while it tries to contact a server, but it should eventually time out if it fails.  If this is the issue, have you tried unchecking that box?  It may be hanging on a networking issue (you can always re-enabled ntpd later.).

Comment: i have same problem, i can't stick the case synchronize and the forward button doesn't work too.
i'am just install the system fedora 15 x64 from netboot cd